# Rails STI: Force superclass to delegate associations to subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

Here's the STI setup I've got so far:

```
class PhoneCall < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_phone_number, class_name: "PhoneNumber"
  belongs_to :to_phone_number, class_name: "PhoneNumber"
end

class OutgoingPhoneCall < PhoneCall
  has_one :user, through: :from_phone_number
end

class IncomingPhoneCall < PhoneCall
  has_one :user, through: :to_phone_number
end
```

You'll see that I expect a `User` at the end of either a `from` or `to` depending on its direction.

This works fine in some cases:

```
OutgoingPhoneCall.joins(:user).where(user: { id: 2 })
```

...gets me exactly what I want.

However, I cannot make the same call on the superclass

```
PhoneCall.joins(:user).where(user: {id: 2}).count
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'user' was not found on PhoneCall; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:218:in `find_reflection'
```

I would like a clean way to get a `User`'s phone calls without having to query twice.

How can I nudge my superclass `PhoneCall` to delegate this association to its subclasses?

Or, alternately, is there a way to get `.joins` to use the subclasses when querying?

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query like this:

```
PhoneCall.joins(from_phone_number: :user, to_phone_number: :user).where(users: {id: 2})
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work, because joining multiple associations is an AND, not an OR. See section 12.2.2 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations